# Single not equal to operator for multiple values of different data types

Tags: sas, where-clause, proc-sql

Is there any function in sas that can be used within proc sql to filter out multiple values of different data types, such as, '0','.','#NA' in a single statement?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for the IN operator?

```
where X not in ('0','.','#NA')
```

Comment: I had tried this expression earlier but it gives me error saying that 'Expression using IN has components that are of different data types.'

Comment: Then the variable is not a character variable. In which case it cannot have the value NA as that is a character string.  Try `X not in (0,.)`.  Since SAS treats 0 and missing as FALSE and any other number as TRUE you could just treat X as a boolean value.  `where x`

Comment: If the variable is a number You can use: where x>0